# freemarker example to transform csv to xml

Tags: java, freemarker

Could the expert provide an example to use apache freemarker to transform csv to xml? including the template definition and basic java code to do that... Thanks.

https://freemarker.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

These two questions, generating from CSV, and generating XML, are orthogonal. Only the first one has any specialty, so let's see that first.

A lot depends on how do you load that CSV. I can tell about the case of Apache Commons CSV. You could load the CSV like this (I prefer using named columns, and has a header row that must be ignored):

```
public List<CSVRecord> getCsv() throws IOException {
    try (Reader r = ...) {
        return CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader("foo", "bar", "baaz").withSkipHeaderRecord()
                .parse(r)
                .getRecords();
    }
}
```

You just drop that `List<CSVRecord>` into the data-model, like anything else, in my case under the name `csv`.

At this point you could already use `<#list csv as record>` in the template, but you had to write `${record.get('foo')}` to insert the a cell value, which is verbose. So to make it nicer, I have this extra setup:

```
public class CSVAwareObjectWrapper extends DefaultObjectWrapper {

    public CSVAwareObjectWrapper(Version incompatibleImprovements) {
        super(incompatibleImprovements);
    }

    @Override
    protected TemplateModel handleUnknownType(Object obj) throws TemplateModelException {
        if (obj instanceof CSVRecord) {
            return new CSVRecordModel((CSVRecord) obj);
        }
        return super.handleUnknownType(obj);
    }

    public class CSVRecordModel implements TemplateHashModel {
        private final CSVRecord csvRecord;

        public CSVRecordModel(CSVRecord csvRecord) {
            this.csvRecord = csvRecord;
        }

        @Override
        public TemplateModel get(String key) throws TemplateModelException {
            return wrap(csvRecord.get(key));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() throws TemplateModelException {
            return csvRecord.size() == 0;
        }

    }

}
```

and then I have this where I set up the FreeMarker `Configuration`:

```
cfg.setObjectWrapper(new CSVAwareObjectWrapper(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_27));
```

And now you can do something like this in your template:

```
<records>
<#list csv as record>
  <record>
    <foo>${record.foo}</foo>
    <bar>${record.bar}</bar>
    <baaz>${record.baaz}</baaz>
  </record>
</#list>
</records>
```

Also, don't forget to ensure that [XML auto escaping](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html#dgui_quickstart_template_autoescaping) is active, or else the generated XML will break if you have `&` and such in the CSV.